# get lat/lon values of every start and end point of polyline

Tags: qgis, coordinates, line

I have a polyline shapefile with 166 different line features.  How would one populate the attribute table with x and y values of the start and end points of each line?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have your four columns: X-start; Y-start; X-end; Y-end.  Using the field calculator for each column update using:

```
$x_at(0)
$x_at(-1)
$y_at(0)
$y_at(-1)
```

This asks for the coordinate at the start of the line (the zero) and the end of the line (the negative one).  This will provide you with a decimal latitude and longitude, so ensure the columns are floats.

EDIT: Thanks to the_darkside's comments please note this won't work on multi lines, due to the multiple beginnings and ends.

Comment: When I input these expressions, I get the error: expression is invalid.  Any possible reason?

Comment: And when I use the expression `xat(0)` I get the following error: `An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string:
Index is out of range`

Comment: index being out of range sounds like you don't have anything for the expression to work on.  I've not had this problem before.  A couple of things you could check: your using the expression on a line? the columns being updated are the right data type? projection(??) is in metres?

Comment: Oh I understand why, it's because its a multipart feature so there are multiple start and end points

Answer (score 4):

In the attribute view create your new columns as decimal (floats).

Then enable editing, and use expressions to update the columns.

To get the latitude (x-coordinate) of the start of a line feature, use the expression `x_at(0)`. To get the end of a line feature use `x_at(-1)`. Repeat for your longitudes (y-coordinates). You select the column, type in the expression, and hit "Update All".

This assumes your data is in lat-long (ESPG:4326 most likely). If not, transform to that and save, or transform within the expression. Here my data is in EPSG:27700 and I want lat-long (EPSG:4326):

```
x(
start_point(
 transform( $geometry, 'EPSG:27700', 'EPSG:4326' ) 
 )
 )
```

Replace `x` with `y` and `start_point` with `end_point` for your four columns.