# Update Eastings, Northings of linear feature

Tags: qgis, coordinates

Using QGIS, need to update easting and Northing.

We have a number of rights of way across the National Park, we need them to be updated as far as the centroid of each one.  We also need to know how to update the start and finish of each line.

The co-ordinates of the centre point of each of the linear objects.  In British National Grid (BNG) if at all possible.

Comment: do have some specific values in mind for the new start end points?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [get lat/lon values of every start and end point of polyline](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199629/get-lat-lon-values-of-every-start-and-end-point-of-polyline). To get the centroid for each line, you could use the **Field Calculator** with the expression `x($geometry)` for the x-coordinate; `y($geometry)` for the y-coordinate.

Comment: Can you not calculate the values in eastings and northings, or do they require to be in lat/lon? @Joseph Thanks.

Comment: No @iant, I don't have specific values in mind, they are already preset. Routes are all over the National Park

Comment: `x_at(0)` Start of Line & `x_at(-1)` End of Line in the coordinate you are using (British National Grid Coordinates)